# Стили для кнопки

Tags: css

Люди добрые, подскажите, как сделать вот такое основание у кнопки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a class="btn" href="">Заказать</a>

.btn {
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
  background: radial-gradient(at 40px -20px, #6EA7F6, #1F84E6);
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/zojxrL9e/3/
```

Comment: `border-bottom: solid 4px #1655ba;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.btn {
  background: radial-gradient(at 50% 0%, #ffffff14 -300px -300px, #2184e2);
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 360px;
  height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-bottom: 10px solid #00439e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="#!">Заказать</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  background: #2084e6;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

button:active {
  transform: scaleX(0.9) translateY(4px);
}

button:not(:active) {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #0447a2;
}
```

```html
<button>Press</button>
```